# URL name keeps appending to end Django

Tags: python, django, url-mapping

I am running into a few issues regarding URL mappings in Django.  I have the following code:

table.html:

```
<form id="filter_form" method="post" action="update_filters/">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Report" />
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^update_filters/', views.filter_report, name='update_filters'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def filter_report(request):
    # Code in the function
    return render(request, 'autotester/table.html', context)
```

and everything works, but when I hit the "Report" button multiple times I get:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/autotester/update_filters
127.0.0.1:8000/autotester/update_filters/update_filters
127.0.0.1:8000/autotester/update_filters/update_filters/update_filters  
etc
```

and I have no idea what's causing it. There has to be some sort of simple fix for this but I just can't find it and I have been trying to figure this out for 3 hours now and my brain is just fried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `{% url 'update_filters' %}` template tag. And also add `$` at the end of the regular expression in your url definition.

```
url(r'^update_filters/$', views.filter_report, name='update_filters'),
```

Comment: That did it.  Do you know why that fixes it? Or can you point me towards a reference that explains it?  I just want to understand.

Comment: The `$` symbol means the URL have to end there, and does not allow to append anything after.

Comment: Oh well that to, but I meant why `{% url 'update_filters' %}` stopped my problem.  I had the `$` there before, but when I hit the _Report_ button more than once it would throw an error saying it didn't know where _autotester/update_filters/update_filters_ was

Comment: Why is here: If you write `<form id="filter_form" method="post" action="/update_filters/">` it should work. You were missing `/` at the beginning, instead `{% url 'update_filters' %}` will print it in the rigth way.